# Failed to fetch tabular content from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script using requests library to get the tabular content available in a webpage. When I visit that site manually using this [link](https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?ticker=C679131&startdate=10%2F03%2F2019&enddate=10%2F03%2F2020), I see a page in which I need to hit the `AGREE` button first in order to see the tabular content.

Once again this is the [website link](https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?ticker=C679131&startdate=10%2F03%2F2019&enddate=10%2F03%2F2020)

I tried to observe closely in the network section in chrome dev tools and mimicked the same using the script below to access the content. However, all I get is the following whereas I'm supposed to get the tabular content in some json format according to dev tools.

Output I'm getting:

```
b'\n\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n\n\n{}'
```

Expected output (truncated):

```
{T:{"Columns":[{"tradeQuantity":"1125000","quantityAsString":"1125000",
```

I've tried with:

```
import json
import requests

start_url = 'https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?'
link = 'https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/bondSearch.jsp'

qsp = {
    'ticker': 'C679131',
    'startdate': '10/03/2019',
    'enddate': '10/03/2020'
}

payload = {
    'postData': {'Keywords':[]},
    'ticker': 'C679131',
    'startDate': '',
    'endDate': '',
    'showResultsAs': 'B',
    'debtOrAssetClass': '',
    'spdsType': ''
}

params = {
    'count': '20',
    'sortfield': 'tradeDate',
    'sorttype': '2',
    'start': '0',
    'searchtype': 'T',
    'query': {"Keywords":[{"Name":"securityId","Value":"C679131"},{"Name":"tradeDate","minValue":"10/03/2019","maxValue":"10/03/2020"}]}
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/UserAgreement.jsp'
    r = s.post(start_url,params=qsp,data=payload)
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?ticker=C679131&startdate=10%2F03%2F2019&enddate=10%2F03%2F2020'
    s.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
    r = s.post(link,json=params)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)
```

> How can I get the tabular content from that webpage using requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a call to :

```
POST https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/finralogin.jsp
```

while storing cookies using `requests.Session()`. Also, the `Referer` header is needed for the call to :

```
POST https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/bondSearch.jsp
```

After that, the result is not quite JSON as pointed by baduker, you can use regex to remodel it :

```
import requests
from urllib import parse
import json
import re
import pandas as pd 

host = "https://finra-markets.morningstar.com"
path = "/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp"

qsp = {
    'ticker': 'C679131',
    'startdate': '10/03/2019',
    'enddate': '10/03/2020'
}
s = requests.Session()

s.post("https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/finralogin.jsp",
    data = {
        "redirectPage": f"{path}?{parse.urlencode(qsp)}"
    }
)
r = s.post("https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/bondSearch.jsp",
    headers= {
        "Referer": f"{host}{path}?{parse.urlencode(qsp)}",
    },
    data = {
        "count": 20,
        "sortfield": "tradeDate",
        "sorttype": 2,
        "start": 0,
        "searchtype": "T",
        "query": json.dumps({
            "Keywords":[
                {"Name":"securityId","Value": qsp["ticker"]},
                {"Name":"tradeDate","minValue": qsp["startdate"],"maxValue":qsp["enddate"]}
            ]
        })
})

dataReg = re.search('{T:(.*)}', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))

df = pd.DataFrame(data["Columns"])

print(df)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeWithCookies)

Output:

```
   tradeQuantity quantityAsString timeOfExecution settlementDate tradeModifier secondModifier specialPriceIndicator  ...  tradeDate symbol cusip callable commissionIndicator ATSIndicator remuneration
0        1125000          1125000        11:46:02      10/2/2020             _              _                     -  ...  10/2/2020   None  None     None                   N                         N
1          60000            60000        10:23:55      10/5/2020             _              _                     -  ...  10/1/2020   None  None     None                   N                         N
2          60000            60000        10:23:54      10/5/2020             _              _                     -  ...  10/1/2020   None  None     None                   M                         M
3         200000           200000        16:27:43      10/2/2020             _              _                     -  ...  9/30/2020   None  None     None                                              
4         200000           200000        16:27:43      10/2/2020             _              _                     -  ...  9/30/2020   None  None     None                   N                         N
5        2900000          2900000        15:39:16      10/2/2020             _              _                     -  ...  9/30/2020   None  None     None                   M                         M
6          20000            20000        12:24:48      10/2/2020             _              _                     -  ...  9/30/2020   None  None     None                   M                         M
.........
```

In the Chrome Developer console, in the network tab you can right click : "headers options/Set Cookies" to quickly catch which call are setting cookies

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. I have one question on this. Where did you find that the first requests has to be made to this `https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/finralogin.jsp` url? I combed through the dev tools but could not find it. I'm using chrome dev tools by the way. Thanks.

Comment: @SMTH you need to open an incognito window, show dev console network tab and then copy paste the url. If you filter the header "set-cookies" you can catch it: see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tOlo.png).

Comment: @SMTH or instead of opening an incognito window, you can go to "application" tab, go to cookies, delete all of them and refresh the page

Comment: Right you are @Bertrand Martel. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to correctly mimic the request with the exact same headers and cookies. I took the cookie raw string from the Developer Tool.

Here's how to get the raw text data:

```
import json
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests

link = 'https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/bondSearch.jsp'

payload = {
    'count': '20',
    'sortfield': 'tradeDate',
    'sorttype': '2',
    'start': '0',
    'searchtype': 'T',
    'query': {"Keywords": [{"Name": "securityId", "Value": "C679131"},
                           {"Name": "tradeDate", "minValue": "10/03/2019", "maxValue": "10/03/2020"}]}
}

cookies_raw_data = "__cfduid=db2d21a652ef313fcff3704bd87e839401602408581; qs_wsid=1CBF0E77A1169ED03A3EB86A6A8A991D; __cfruid=0ef7fb90b47b06df86311ff32918c0c9c441617d-1602408582; SessionID=1CBF0E77A1169ED03A3EB86A6A8A991D; UsrID=41151; UsrName=FINRA.QSAPIDEF@morningstar.com; Instid=FINRA; msFinraHasAgreed=true"
cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie.load(cookies_raw_data)

cookies = {}
for key, morsel in cookie.items():
    cookies[key] = morsel.value

ref_payload = urlencode(dict(ticker="C679131", startdate="10/03/2019", enddate="10/03/2020"))

referer = f"https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?{ref_payload}"

headers = {
    "Accept": "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "278",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host": "finra-markets.morningstar.com",
    "Origin": "https://finra-markets.morningstar.com",
    "Referer": referer,
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

response = requests.post(link, data=urlencode(payload), headers=headers, cookies=cookies).text
print(response.strip())
```

Output:

```
{T:{"Columns":[{"tradeQuantity":"1125000","quantityAsString":"1125000","timeOfExecution":"11:46:02","settlementDate":"10/2/2020","tradeModifier":"_","secondModifier":"_","specialPriceIndicator":"-","asOfTrade":"-","reportingParty":"B","tradeStatus":"T","reportingPartyType":"D","contraPartyType":"C","securityId":"C679131","issueIdentifier":"EXC4479862","descriptionOfIssuer":"EXELON CORP","subproductType":"Corporate Bond","couponRate":3.497,"maturityDate":"06/01/2022","price":104.576,"yield":0.584,"tradeDate":"10/2/2020","symbol":null,"cusip":null,"callable":null,"commissionIndicator":"N","ATSIndicator":" ","remuneration":"N"},{"tradeQuantity":"60000","quantityAsString":"60000","timeOfExecution":"10:23:55","settlementDate":"10/5/2020","tradeModifier":"_","secondModifier":"_","specialPriceIndicator":"-","asOfTrade":"-","reportingParty":"S","tradeStatus":"T","reportingPartyType":"D",
and so on...
```

The data itself is a plain text that turns out to be an invalid `JSON`. I couldn't parse it right away. After a couple of tries, I realized that the first key `T` is not in `"` so this wasn't passing as a valid `JSON` but... a simple hack did the trick!

To get the `JSON` object use this (I'll edit this if I find a less hacky way):

```
data = json.loads(response.strip()[3:-1])
for t in data['Columns']:
    print(f"{t['descriptionOfIssuer']} - {t['tradeQuantity']} - {t['price']}")
```

Output:

```
EXELON CORP - 1125000 - 104.576
EXELON CORP - 60000 - 104.642
EXELON CORP - 60000 - 104.618
EXELON CORP - 200000 - 104.612
EXELON CORP - 200000 - 104.612
EXELON CORP - 2900000 - 104.597
EXELON CORP - 20000 - 104.6
EXELON CORP - 225000 - 104.553
EXELON CORP - 64000 - 104.581
EXELON CORP - 64000 - 104.596
EXELON CORP - 50000 - 104.553
EXELON CORP - 2100000 - 104.634
EXELON CORP - 230000 - 104.551
EXELON CORP - 97000 - 104.566
EXELON CORP - 15000 - 104.551
EXELON CORP - 342000 - 104.582
EXELON CORP - 1400000 - 104.616
EXELON CORP - 200000 - 104.501
EXELON CORP - 200000 - 104.511
EXELON CORP - 220000 - 104.397
```

EDIT:

To prove that even short-lived (and hard-coded) cookies are better than no data at all, here's a modified version of the script that produces a data dump for that ticker you're after.

This should work even with those damned cookies, becasue you're requesting archival data that's unlikely to change. So, you can fetch it, save it, and move on.

Note: if the cookies that I'm using are outdated, just replace these with whatever values you have in the `Developer Tool -> XHR -> bondSearch.jsp -> Headers -> Request Headers -> Cookie`:

- `__cfduid`
- `qs_wsid`
- `__cfruid`
- `SessionID` (this is always the same as `qs_wsid`

The code:

```
import json
import time
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests


ref_payload = urlencode(dict(ticker="C679131", startdate="10/03/2019", enddate="10/03/2020"))
referer = f"https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondTradeActivitySearchResult.jsp?{ref_payload}"

headers = {
    "Accept": "text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "278",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host": "finra-markets.morningstar.com",
    "Origin": "https://finra-markets.morningstar.com",
    "Referer": referer,
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

cookies = {
    "__cfduid": "d1820cb5f1d1e8ec40513d0f8326ce1881602492151",
    "qs_wsid": "92CD4948C2AC7FCEC0989B34B86C1ADB",
    "__cfruid": "4dec9a2deb6d70c86ee5b8fa4046748994ef6254-1602492151}",
    "SessionID": "92CD4948C2AC7FCEC0989B34B86C1ADB",
    "UsrID": "41151",
    "UsrName": "FINRA.QSAPIDEF@morningstar.com",
    "Instid": "FINRA",
    "msFinraHasAgreed": "true",
}

start_counter = 0
final_output = []
while True:
    payload = {
        'count': '20',
        'sortfield': 'tradeDate',
        'sorttype': '2',
        'start': str(start_counter),
        'searchtype': 'T',
        'query': {
            "Keywords": [
                {"Name": "securityId", "Value": "C679131"},
                {"Name": "tradeDate", "minValue": "10/03/2019", "maxValue": "10/03/2020"},
            ]
        }
    }

    response = requests.post(
        'https://finra-markets.morningstar.com/bondSearch.jsp',
        data=urlencode(payload),
        headers=headers,
        cookies=cookies,
    ).text

    data = json.loads(response.strip()[3:-1])["Columns"]
    if data:
        print(f"Fetching data for counter {start_counter}...")
        final_output.extend(data)
        start_counter += 20
    else:
        break

with open(f"data_dump_securityID_C679131.json", "w") as d:
    json.dump(final_output, d, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Your suggested script should not work now or won't work few hours from now. Hardcoded cookies is the last option I can think of implementing as they are always short lived and meant to be broken. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't mention any constraints in your question. True, you weren't using cookies but that didn't get you the data either. The cookies are short-lived but that's long enough to do something. Especially in this case, since you're fetching stale data, which won't change, so you can grab the data, save it, and move on. If you find a better approach, do let me know. By the way, you could at least appreciate the effort thou.